# Qual è l'origine dell'espressione "con questi chiari di luna"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-origin

***“Con questi chiari di luna”*** è un espressione molto comune usata per indicare un momento critico, un periodo difficile, soprattutto sotto il profilo economico.

Probabilmente viene chiamata in causa la luna, in senso figurato, perché la sua luce fioca (chiaro) rende poco visibili  i particolari e le immagini.

Ma qual è la vera origine di questo modo di dire? E soprattutto, perché si usa in riferimento a questioni di soldi e di disagio economico?

Comment: Non so l'origine della locuzione, ma “chiaro” vuol dire sicuramente “luminoso”, non “fioco” («Luce, luminosità: *un bel ch. di luna*; *al ch. del sole*, *al ch. del giorno*; *fare le cose al ch. del giorno*, apertamente, non in segreto, senza imbrogli», [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chiaro/))

Comment: Questo  rende ancora più 'oscuro' l'uso e l'origine del modo di dire.

Comment: :-) In effetti... Riporto quello dice il *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci, che però non è illuminante ma anzi infittisce il buio: «Frase ironica con cui si introduce un discorso che tende a dimostrare come certe cose non siano possibili in una certa situazione o date certe premesse».

Comment: Questo [sito web](http://www.terremarsicane.it/marsica/node/12402) propone come origine del detto il sintagma latino *clara jejunia* che significa "manifesti digiuni" (i "manifesti digiuni" della gente in periodi di fame).

Comment: C'è anche chi pensa che l'origine sia nel linguaggio dei pescatori: quando ci sono i chiari di luna, la pesca è molto scarsa.

Comment: @Charo - interessanti entrambe le ipotesi. Molto diverse tra loro e rispetto anche a quella contadina. Non pensavo che l'origine fosse così 'poco chiara'. :)

Comment: La mia interpretazione naive è semplicemente che quando hai pochi soldi eviti di illuminare con candele o lampadine, ma ti accontenti della luce naturale.

Comment: This is all a hard for me to follow, as I am just learning Italian, but it sounds to me rather like it has the same meaning of "Through a glass, darkly", which is a rather famous saying in English.

Comment: @Msfolly - no, the expression is used to refer to difficult times, especially from an economic perspective.

Comment: @Josh61 Thank you for the clarification.  From what I can decipher, it is interesting, and I like learning about idioms and axioms.  As you can see, so far I am not understanding much! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Come noto, nella 'cultura' contadina di un tempo l'entità dei raccolti era immaginata come correlata ai cicli lunari, nella 'lettura' dei quali assumevano rilevanza preminente le lune piene.

Quando 'ste lune piene erano irregolari si attendevano raccolti magri; quando no, ottimi raccolti—e quindi anche condizioni di benessere economico.

Ecco perché 'con questi chiari di luna' ha assunto il significato descritto nella domanda.

Comment: Interessante tesi, hai qualche fonte che puoi citare?

Comment: Questa è una conoscenza che si tramanda di generazione in generazione per via orale, non conosco fonti scritte.

Comment: Elberich, non capisco bene la tua risposta (a parte la mancanza di fonti). Che cos'è una “luna piena irregolare”, per esempio?

Comment: Le riferite 'lune piene', nel contesto della risposta, sono gli eventi di luna piena verificantisi durante il periodo dalla semina al raccolto. Si hanno 'lune piene irregolari' allorché nel predetto periodo i predetti eventi sono interferiti—eventualmente in parte—da fenomeni meteorologici che ne impediscono o ne ostacolano il dispiegarsi degli effetti luminosi, @DaG.

Comment: @Elberich: Penso che sia meglio lasciare la parte della risposta che non contiene la tua opinione sulla situazione d'Italia.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider:  La tua opinione è rispettabile, ma una risposta su una domanda sulla lingua italiana non è il posto adatto per esprimerla.

Comment: Adesso mi sembra una risposta interessante: la spiegazione mi sembra plausibile.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: Puoi esprimere un'opinione in un commento, ma non farlo nella risposta, per favore.

Comment: @charo, scusa, mi sono riconnesso solo ora. Grazie per l'edit.

Comment: Peraltro non c'era nulla di male. La situazione attuale dell'Italia fornisce un esempio molto chiaro di applicazione di quell'espressione.

Answer (score -1):

Credo che l’espressione "con questi chiari di luna"
in ambito finanziario venga utilizzata per paragonare il mondo agrario, che  con poca luce notturna anche il raccolto soffra un ritardo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo intervento. Questo si era più o meno detto nell'altra risposta: sarebbe interessante corredarlo con qualche fonte.